# Gmail Add-ons starting to show up on iOS?

Tags: ios, gmail-addons

I'm a Gmail Add-on developer with two add-os on the Gmail Add-on marketplace. I've noticed that certain Add-ons like Dropbox, Asana, and Trello, have started to show up inside the Gmail app on iOS. My two apps, however, Wordzen and GMass, are not showing up. I can't figure out why. They only show on Android. Any ideas?

The official Gmail Add-on docs still state that Add-ons aren't supported on iOS, but clearly they are starting to work, since I'm seeing these other Add-ons from these well-known companies show up.

Comment: It is good to know that, Google had been silently working on iOS support. However, at the moment, how well does those addons work ? I am just being curious.

Comment: I’m also curious. I’ve noticed add-ons for Jira and Google Hire within Gmail on iOS. I haven’t been able to find information describing how to develop a similar add-on.